# Using the tree command to tar archive?

Tags: bash, tree, tar

The command tree prints graphically directory structure:

```
tree stary/
```

[Result of the command tree:](http://postimg.org/image/q32bonlc9/)

However, the command tree does not print the contents of a tar archive:

```
10 10.tar
12 12.tar
cr.tar
```

I tried it, but it does not work:

```
tar -tf | tree stary/
```

[Result of the command tree](http://postimg.org/image/qt3i1x7r7/)

How to use the tree command to tar archive?

Comment: You would have to mount the archive as a file system. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/265772/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-tar-file) for some possible solutions.

Answer (score -2):

Use it:

```
less archive.tar.gz | awk '{print $NF}' | tree
```

But be sure that archive doesn't contains files/folders with spaces in the name (space and tab symbols are the default column separators in awk).

Comment: Suggested pipeline just doesn't work. `tree` without arguments (or with them) ignores stdin and shows tree for current dir.

Comment: `tree` has `--fromfile` option which makes it possible to read from stdin. See this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1086501/list-contents-of-tarball-in-tree-format/1545418#1545418